# How can i make this a valid WSDL?

Tags: soap, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I'm trying to generate code from [this WSDL](http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/wsdl/2.0/csw-ebrim-interface.wsdl) using the following command:

```
svcutil /noConfig /language:C# /out:ICatalog.cs http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/wsdl/2.0/csw-ebrim-interface.wsdl
```

However svcutil cannot read it, and the xMethods [WSDL validator](http://xmethods.net/ve2/Tools.po) says it's invalid.

What's invalid about it? How can i get svcutil to generate my interface code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if the WSDL is valid or not but what you are trying to do won't work. [Svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) can generate code only for WSDL files of version 1.1. Yours is a WSDL version 2.0.

The WSDL validator you pointed in your question returns the following message when given your WSDL:

> faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/:definitions'.

It parses the file as WSDL 1.1. and expects the root to be `definitions`, [but that changed](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/WSDL_11vs20.png) in WSDL 2.0 to `description`.

If you have a valid WSDL 2.0 file, [Svcutil2](http://svcutil2.codeplex.com/) might be able to generate the code for you, but this tool isn't stable yet.

To validate the WSDL, I guess you could use the [validator from The Woden project](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WsdlValidator), which isn't stable either, but is basically the only one that I know that has moved passed the "toy project" status.

The idea is this: **version 1.1 is still the "de facto" language when taking WSDL**. Not many WS frameworks have adopted WSDL 2.0 so (just my 2 cents!) I think it's better to stick with "the standard" untill support is fully matured for WSDL 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

try to add reference 
References > Add Reference > COM > System.ServiceModel